# Analytically solving polynomial inequality $n^2-x^2\geq{0}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How do we find the domain of the function $\sqrt{n^2-x^2}$ with $n>0$?

**Attempt to find solution:**

$n^2-x^2\geq{0}$

$(n+x)(n-x)\geq{0}$

Case 1: $(n+x)(n-x)={0}\implies$ $x=n$ or $x=-n$

Case 2: $(n+x)(n-x)>{0}\implies$ $(n+x)>0$ and $(n-x)>0$ or $(n+x)<0$ and $(n-x)<0$

$n>-x$ and $n>x$ or $n<-x$ and $n<x$

$-n<x$ and $n>x$ or $-n>x$ and $n<x$

$x>-n$ and $x<n$ or $x<-n$ and $x>n$

What is wrong with this attempt, why isn't it giving the desired answer $-n\leq x\leq n$ ?

Comment: Hint: Is it possible to have $x<-n$ and $x>n$ simultaneously for $n>0$?  This reduces your "and" to the expression that you're looking for.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ohh thanx... got little confused over thr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My proof:** $\sqrt{n^2-x^2}\ge 0\Rightarrow n^2-x^2\ge 0\Rightarrow n^2\ge x^2\Rightarrow n=|n|\ge |x|\Rightarrow -n\le x\le n$.

---

Problem of your work:

**Case 2:** $(n+x)(n-x)>{0}\implies$ $(n+x)>0$ and $(n-x)>0$ or $(n+x)<0$ and $(n-x)<0$

**Subcase 1:** Suppose $n+x>0$ and $n-x>0$. Then this implies $x>-n$ and $n>x$. Hence $-n<x<n$.

**Subcase 2:** Suppose $n+x<0$ and $n-x<0$. Then this implies $n+x+n-x<0$, which is $2n<0$, then $n<0$, which contradicts to original hypothesis. So **Subcase 2** would not happen.

Comment: that's not what the OP is asking for...

Comment: @Mastrem Added a few content, thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$n^2-x^2\geq 0$$
$$n^2\geq x^2$$
$$|n|\geq |x|$$
$$-n\leq x\leq n$$
Now why your answer isn't correct.
In the first line of your answer you have:
$$n>-x\wedge n>x\equiv n>|x|$$
$$n<-x \wedge n<x\equiv n<|x|$$
The second line of your answer:
$$-n<x\wedge n>x \equiv n>-x\wedge n>x\equiv n>|x|$$
$$-n>x\wedge n<x\equiv n<-x\wedge n<x\equiv n<|x|$$
The third line:
$$x>-n\wedge x<n\equiv -x<n\wedge x<n\equiv n>|x|$$
$$x<-n\wedge x>n\equiv -x>n\wedge x>n\equiv n<|x|$$
So basically you are saying $n$ can take every possible value